# Заполнить spinner данными из сети (json)

Tags: android, android-spinner, rxandroid

Нужно из json получить список категорий и потом поместить в спиннер. (Нужно для поиска товара: категория + текст)
Делаю так :

**Сеть. Retrofit +rxJava**

```
 ViewInterface mvi;
 @Override
 public void getCategories() {
            getObservableCategories().subscribeWith(getObserver());


        }


        public Observable<Categories> getObservableCategories(){
            return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
                    .getCategories("apikeys")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }


        public DisposableObserver<Categories> getObserver(){
            return new DisposableObserver<Categories>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Categories categories) {
                    mvi.displayCategories(categories);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Error"+e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mvi.displayError("Error Data");
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Completed");
                    mvi.hideProgressBar();
                }
            };
        }
```

**Сам спиннер**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                    ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);
                    spinner= view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity()), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categList);
                                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

         AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                Log.d("Selected",(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                            }
                                        };
                                        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);

return view;

}
```

**ArrayList**

```
  @Override
        public void displayCategories(Categories categories) {
            for (int i=0;i<categories.getResults().size();i++) {
              categList.add(categories.getResults().get(i).getCategoryName());
            }

        }
```

Удалось получить массив категорий, но отображаются в спиннере только тогда ,когда спинер в развернутом виде и нельзя нечего выбрать(getItemAtPosition). Заранее спасибо.

**Дополню** Сам спиннер находится во Fragment , а запросы в сеть в другом классе. Если создать массив с категориями прям во фрагменте,то  спиннер  работает нормально. Если передавать(displayCategories) - то только, в раскрытом виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Перенес адаптер

```
adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categ);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

в
`displayCategories(Categories categories)` .